# SBT 'dependsOn' but for publishLocal

Tags: sbt

`dependsOn` compiles all the submodules in the right order if you call it on the top level module.

But the `publishLocal` command ignores these submodules.

Is there any way to, given a multi-module sbt project, get it to compile+publishLocal the submodules in the correct order?

Answer (score 1):

I think a simple solution is just to run `*/publishLocal` which should aggregate over all subprojects (also publishing depends on compilation, so compile+publish is redundant).

But if your setup is more complex and you want to publish some subprojects, but not others, or aggregate some subprojects in another subproject, then follow the answer from @mario-galic: common settings + `.aggregate`.

Answer (score 0):

One solution is to define a sequence of settings dedicated for libraries, say, `commonLibrarySettings`, and then set those settings on each publishable sub-module via `.settings(commonLibrarySettings)`. For example:

```
lazy val commonSettings = Seq(
  organization := "com.example",
  version := "0.1.0-SNAPSHOT",
  scalaVersion := "2.12.6",
  ...
)

lazy val commonLibrarySettings = Seq(
  publishArtifact := true,
  publishArtifact in Test := false,
  publishTo in ThisBuild := Some(if (isSnapshot.value) Opts.resolver.sonatypeSnapshots else Opts.resolver.sonatypeReleases),
  ...
)

lazy val root = (project in file("."))
  .aggregate(core, submodule1, submodule2)

lazy val core = (project in file("core"))
  .settings(commonSettings)

lazy val submodule1 = (project in file("submodule1")) // publishable sub-module
  .settings(commonSettings)
  .settings(commonLibrarySettings)

lazy val submodule2 = (project in file("submodule2")) // publishable sub-module
  .settings(commonSettings)
  .settings(commonLibrarySettings)
```